# Mapping xml to jpa entities using JAXB

Tags: jpa, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

Isn't it possible to map xml to jpa entities using JAXB? Will Eclipselink Moxy be helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Yes you can map JPA entities to XML, and the following are some ways that **EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)** makes this easier.

**1. Bidirectional Mappings**

***Customer***

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="customer", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Address address;

}
```

***Address***

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID")
    @MapsId
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="address")
    private Customer customer;

}
```

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-25.html

**2.  Mapping Compound Key Relationships**

We normally think of mapping a tree of objects to XML, however JAXB supports using the combination of [`@XmlID`/`@XmlIDREF`](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html) to map relationship between nodes representing a graph.  The standard mechanism is one key, to one foreign key.  JPA supports the concept of composite keys and so does MOXy using `@XmlKey` and `@XmlJoinNodes` (similar to `@XmlJoinColumns` in JPA).

***Employee***

```
@Entity
@IdClass(EmployeeId.class)
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name="E_ID")
    @XmlID
    private BigDecimal eId;

    @Id
    @XmlKey
    private String country;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="contact")
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="contact")
    private List<PhoneNumber> contactNumber;

}
```

***PhoneNumber***

```
@Entity
public class PhoneNumber {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="E_ID", referencedColumnName = "E_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name="E_COUNTRY", referencedColumnName = "COUNTRY")
    })
    @XmlJoinNodes( {
        @XmlJoinNode(xmlPath="contact/id/text()", referencedXmlPath="id/text()"),
        @XmlJoinNode(xmlPath="contact/country/text()", referencedXmlPath="country/text()")
    })
    private Employee contact;

}
```

***For More Information***

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JPA/CompoundPrimaryKeys

**3.  MOXy allows for Composite and Embedded Keys**

JPA can also use embedded key classes to represent composite keys.  MOXy also supports this style of composite keys.

***For More Information***

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JPA/EmbeddedIdClass

**4.  EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) and EclipseLink JPA Have Shared Concepts**

EclipseLink provides both JAXB and JPA implementations that share a common core.  This means that they share many of the same concepts, such as:

***Virtual Access Methods***

EclipseLink supports the concept of virtual properties.  This is useful when creating a multi-tenant application where you want per-tenant customizations.  This concept is upported in both EclipseLink's JPA and JAXB implementations.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/moxy-extensible-models-multi-tenant.html
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Extensibility

Comment: is it possible for JAXB(MOXy) to convert xsd files to POJO files with JPA mappings already(Entity, Column, etc)?