# How to convert Hibernate POJO Classes to XML for JUnit Testing

Tags: xml, hibernate, junit, jaxb, pojo

I have to work on a project which I try to write JUNIT tests for service layer. I have to check whether same data is writing to database (with same scenario and inputs) or not.

First I planned to create data from user interface manually then I convert Hibernate POJO Classes to XML and save this as a sample result value. Then while testing with JUnit, I planned to compare it with my sample XML results. Thus if JUnit result data is same with manually created sample data I can understand that Junit test is successful.

My question is: how can I convert hibernate annotations and POJO classes to XML? I researched about JAXB but I couldn't find a way to convert this to XML.

My model class is like this.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="USERSS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "Seq_Gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Seq_Gen", sequenceName = "S_")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name="ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="NAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="SURNAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    @Column(name="MAIL", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String mail;

    @Column(name="PASSWORD", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String password;


    //private UserRoles UserRoles;

    public User() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public User(int id, String name, String surname, String mail,
            String password) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //@Column(name="NAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String htmlInputText) {
        this.name = htmlInputText;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String htmlInputText) {
        this.surname = htmlInputText;
    }    


    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setMail(String htmlInputText) {
        this.mail = htmlInputText;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mapping xml to jpa entities using JAXB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395450/mapping-xml-to-jpa-entities-using-jaxb)

Comment: Don't forget that the ID will be different each time so it will not be an exact match to your expected XML.

Comment: @JohnB i think that i dont regenerate id, and i test it dedicated samples so its not a problem from now. Then how can i solve (at)JoinColumn, (at)OneToMany , (at)ManyToOne columns. Also i take proxy object, (at)OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) line because of LAZY fetch. –